Celery max_retries with ack_task=True with reject_on_worker_lost=True
I want to ask a question regarding the usage of max_tries with the options reject_on_worker_lost=True and ack_late=True.
If I enable the above settings below for a task
@shared_task(acks_late=True, reject_on_worker_lost=True, max_retries=4)

will it still count the max retries(will the max retries work) when there is a reject on worker loss preventing infinite queueing? I didn't find a specific area in the documentation regarding this as well
